# facebook login - opera doesn't close window after login

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, opera, facebook-login

I have used the login using facebook javascript SDK.
When I loggin with Opera using facebook login - opera doesn't close.

I have used Opera version 12.00.

Why not close the opera browser automatically?

Code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId      : 'KEY',
                status     : true, 
                cookie     : true,
                xfbml      : true,
                oauth      : true
            });

(function(d){
            var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk';
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {
                return;
            }
            js = d.createElement('script');
            js.id = id;
            js.async = true;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/cs_CZ/all.js";
            d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
        }(document));

$("#btnFBLogin").live("click", function(){
            FB.login(function(response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    FB.api('/me', function(response) {

            //Loggin

                    });
                } else {
                }
            }, {
                scope: 'email user_photos user_birthday'
            });

            return false;
        });

    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Opera is notoriously known for doing 'weird' things.
In this case, Opera opens a new tab instead of a real popup, and subsequently refuses to let the opening window actually close it down.

Comment: Hi JohnMalcolm, it would be great to get a link where I can see this code running live.

Comment: I've got absolutely same behaviour, login popup works in all browsers but not in Opera.

Comment: I am also facing the same behavior for Opera.